# Should I use mySQL Table Views or Spring Data JPA projections?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have a mySQL relational database with football statistics that contains a table matches. I created a method in my Spring project to build a standings table. This method uses a projection because I need each match object to include the two team objects. This response (get all matches + get the two teams in each match) takes around 7 seconds.

The same information but within a View in my database takes 0.231 seconds.

I'm very new to Spring Data so my question is. Should I use table views when I need to join tables? Is there any advice against doing so?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with using table views. You can map to them with JPA @Table annotation.

The only potential problem is when migrating databases (you will have to make sure Views are migrated correctly).

Hope this helps.